# Word Search Game Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a Word Search Game and I'm trying to figure out how to generate my chosen words onto the HTML grid I created. Somebody already helped me find a way to randomly generate the words into a row and column, but it generates the whole word into a cell, whereas I need each letter of the word to be randomly placed in an individual cell (If that makes sense).

```
const myWords = ["LOL", "HEY", "TOYS", "YES", "SIR", "JOY"]; 

for (let i = 0; i <myWords.length; i++) 
    {
const randomIndex = length => Math.floor(Math.random()*length);
const table = document.querySelector('table');
const randomRow = table.rows[randomIndex(myWords.length)];
const randomCell = randomRow.cells[randomIndex(myWords.length)];
const randomWord = myWords[Math.floor(Math.random() * myWords.length)];
randomCell.innerText = randomWord;   
    }
```

I planned on having the words horizontal, vertical and diagonal. I tried searching through Stack Overflow and Github, with no success. Can someone help?

Comment: You can refer 「[How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)」, and re-edit your question to get help faster

Comment: I don't understand 'each letter of the word to be randomly placed'. In a word search the letters of a word usually have to be placed sequentially in some way. Could you explain in more detail what is required?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome,
The code is fully complete and works fully,
Credits to [lizhineng](https://github.com/lizhineng/word-search-game)

```js
/**
 * Returns a random integer between min and max
 *
 * @param {Number} min
 * @param {Number} max
 * @return {Number}
 */
if (typeof Math.rangeInt != 'function') {
  Math.rangeInt = function(min, max){
    if (max == undefined) {
        max = min;
        min = 0;
    }
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }
}

/**
 * Mege two objects
 *
 * @param {Object} o1 Object 1
 * @param {Object} o2 Object 2
 * @return {Object}
 */
if (typeof Object.merge != 'function') {
  Object.merge = function(o1, o2) {
    for (var i in o1) {
      o2[i] = o1[i];
    }
    return o2;
  }
}
(function(){
  'use strict';

  // Extend the element method
  Element.prototype.wordSearch = function(settings) {
    return new WordSearch(this, settings);
  }

  /**
   * Word seach
   *
   * @param {Element} wrapWl the game's wrap element
   * @param {Array} settings
   * constructor
   */
  function WordSearch(wrapEl, settings) {
    this.wrapEl = wrapEl;

    // Add `.ws-area` to wrap element
    this.wrapEl.classList.add('ws-area');

    //Words solved.
    this.solved = 0;

    // Default settings
    var default_settings = {
      'directions': ['W', 'N', 'WN', 'EN'],
      'gridSize': 10,
      'words': ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'],
      'wordsList' : [],
      'debug': false
    }
    this.settings = Object.merge(settings, default_settings);

    // Check the words' length if it is overflow the grid
    if (this.parseWords(this.settings.gridSize)) {
      // Add words into the matrix data
      var isWorked = false;

      while (isWorked == false) {
        // initialize the application
        this.initialize();

        isWorked = this.addWords();
      }

      // Fill up the remaining blank items
      if (!this.settings.debug) {
        this.fillUpFools();
      }

      // Draw the matrix into wrap element
      this.drawmatrix();
    }
  }

  /**
   * Parse words
   * @param {Number} Max size
   * @return {Boolean}
   */
  WordSearch.prototype.parseWords = function(maxSize) {
    var itWorked = true;

    for (var i = 0; i < this.settings.words.length; i++) {
      // Convert all the letters to upper case      
      this.settings.wordsList[i] =  this.settings.words[i].trim();
      this.settings.words[i] =  removeDiacritics(this.settings.wordsList[i].trim().toUpperCase());

      var word = this.settings.words[i];
      if (word.length > maxSize) {
        alert('The length of word `' + word + '` is overflow the gridSize.');
        console.error('The length of word `' + word + '` is overflow the gridSize.');
        itWorked = false;
      }
    }

    return itWorked;
  }

  /**
   * Put the words into the matrix
   */
  WordSearch.prototype.addWords = function() {
      var keepGoing = true,
        counter = 0,
        isWorked = true;

      while (keepGoing) {
        // Getting random direction
        var dir = this.settings.directions[Math.rangeInt(this.settings.directions.length - 1)],
          result = this.addWord(this.settings.words[counter], dir),
          isWorked = true;

        if (result == false) {
          keepGoing = false;
          isWorked = false;
        }

        counter++;
        if (counter >= this.settings.words.length) {
          keepGoing = false;
        }
      }

      return isWorked;
  }

  /**
   * Add word into the matrix
   *
   * @param {String} word
   * @param {Number} direction
   */
  WordSearch.prototype.addWord = function(word, direction) {
    var itWorked = true,
      directions = {
        'W': [0, 1], // Horizontal (From left to right)
        'N': [1, 0], // Vertical (From top to bottom)
        'WN': [1, 1], // From top left to bottom right
        'EN': [1, -1] // From top right to bottom left
      },
      row, col; // y, x

    switch (direction) {
      case 'W': // Horizontal (From left to right)
        var row = Math.rangeInt(this.settings.gridSize  - 1),
          col = Math.rangeInt(this.settings.gridSize - word.length);
        break;

      case 'N': // Vertical (From top to bottom)
        var row = Math.rangeInt(this.settings.gridSize - word.length),
          col = Math.rangeInt(this.settings.gridSize  - 1);
        break;

      case 'WN': // From top left to bottom right
        var row = Math.rangeInt(this.settings.gridSize - word.length),
          col = Math.rangeInt(this.settings.gridSize - word.length);
        break;

      case 'EN': // From top right to bottom left
        var row = Math.rangeInt(this.settings.gridSize - word.length),
          col = Math.rangeInt(word.length - 1, this.settings.gridSize - 1);
        break;

      default:
        var error = 'UNKNOWN DIRECTION ' + direction + '!';
        alert(error);
        console.log(error);
        break;
    }

    // Add words to the matrix
    for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
      var newRow = row + i * directions[direction][0],
        newCol = col + i * directions[direction][1];

      // The letter on the board
      var origin = this.matrix[newRow][newCol].letter;

      if (origin == '.' || origin == word[i]) {
        this.matrix[newRow][newCol].letter = word[i];
      } else {
        itWorked = false;
      }
    }

    return itWorked;
  }

  /**
   * Initialize the application
   */
  WordSearch.prototype.initialize = function() {
    /**
     * Letter matrix
     *
     * param {Array}
     */
    this.matrix = [];

    /**
     * Selection from
     * @Param {Object}
     */
    this.selectFrom = null;

    /**
     * Selected items
     */
    this.selected = [];

    this.initmatrix(this.settings.gridSize);
  }

  /**
   * Fill default items into the matrix
   * @param {Number} size Grid size
   */
  WordSearch.prototype.initmatrix = function(size) {
    for (var row = 0; row < size; row++) {
      for (var col = 0; col < size; col++) {
        var item = {
          letter: '.', // Default value
          row: row,
          col: col
        }

        if (!this.matrix[row]) {
          this.matrix[row] = [];
        }

        this.matrix[row][col] = item;
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Draw the matrix
   */
  WordSearch.prototype.drawmatrix = function() {
    for (var row = 0; row < this.settings.gridSize; row++) {
      // New row
      var divEl = document.createElement('div');
      divEl.setAttribute('class', 'ws-row');
      this.wrapEl.appendChild(divEl);

      for (var col = 0; col < this.settings.gridSize; col++) {
        var cvEl = document.createElement('canvas');
        cvEl.setAttribute('class', 'ws-col');
        cvEl.setAttribute('width', 40);
        cvEl.setAttribute('height', 40);

        // Fill text in middle center
        var x = cvEl.width / 2,
          y = cvEl.height / 2;

        var ctx = cvEl.getContext('2d');
        ctx.font = '400 28px Calibri';
        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
        ctx.fillStyle = '#333'; // Text color
        ctx.fillText(this.matrix[row][col].letter, x, y);

        // Add event listeners
        cvEl.addEventListener('mousedown', this.onMousedown(this.matrix[row][col]));
        cvEl.addEventListener('mouseover', this.onMouseover(this.matrix[row][col]));
        cvEl.addEventListener('mouseup', this.onMouseup());

        divEl.appendChild(cvEl);
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Fill up the remaining items
   */
  WordSearch.prototype.fillUpFools = function() {
    var rangeLanguage = searchLanguage(this.settings.words[0].split('')[0]);
    for (var row = 0; row < this.settings.gridSize; row++) {
      for (var col = 0; col < this.settings.gridSize; col++) {
        if (this.matrix[row][col].letter == '.') {
          // Math.rangeInt(65, 90) => A ~ Z
          this.matrix[row][col].letter = String.fromCharCode(Math.rangeInt(rangeLanguage[0], rangeLanguage[1]));
        }
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Returns matrix items
   * @param rowFrom
   * @param colFrom
   * @param rowTo
   * @param colTo
   * @return {Array}
   */
  WordSearch.prototype.getItems = function(rowFrom, colFrom, rowTo, colTo) {
    var items = [];

    if ( rowFrom === rowTo || colFrom === colTo || Math.abs(rowTo - rowFrom) == Math.abs(colTo - colFrom) ) {
      var shiftY = (rowFrom === rowTo) ? 0 : (rowTo > rowFrom) ? 1 : -1,
        shiftX = (colFrom === colTo) ? 0 : (colTo > colFrom) ? 1 : -1,
        row = rowFrom,
        col = colFrom;

      items.push(this.getItem(row, col));
      do {
        row += shiftY;
        col += shiftX;
        items.push(this.getItem(row, col));
      } while( row !== rowTo || col !== colTo );
    }

    return items;
  }

  /**
   * Returns matrix item
   * @param {Number} row
   * @param {Number} col
   * @return {*}
   */
  WordSearch.prototype.getItem = function(row, col) {
    return (this.matrix[row] ? this.matrix[row][col] : undefined);
  }

  /**
   * Clear the exist highlights
   */
  WordSearch.prototype.clearHighlight = function() {
    var selectedEls = document.querySelectorAll('.ws-selected');
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedEls.length; i++) {
      selectedEls[i].classList.remove('ws-selected');
    }
  }

  /**
   * Lookup if the wordlist contains the selected
   * @param {Array} selected
   */
  WordSearch.prototype.lookup = function(selected) {
    var words = [''];

    for (var i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
      words[0] += selected[i].letter;
    }
    words.push(words[0].split('').reverse().join(''));

    if (this.settings.words.indexOf(words[0]) > -1 ||
        this.settings.words.indexOf(words[1]) > -1) {
      for (var i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
        var row = selected[i].row + 1,
          col = selected[i].col + 1,
          el = document.querySelector('.ws-area .ws-row:nth-child(' + row + ') .ws-col:nth-child(' + col + ')');

        el.classList.add('ws-found');
      }

      //Cross word off list.
      var wordList = document.querySelector(".ws-words");
      var wordListItems = wordList.getElementsByTagName("li");
      for(var i=0; i<wordListItems.length; i++){
        if(words[0] == removeDiacritics(wordListItems[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase())){         
          if(wordListItems[i].innerHTML != "<del>"+wordListItems[i].innerHTML+"</del>") { //Check the word is never found
            wordListItems[i].innerHTML = "<del>"+wordListItems[i].innerHTML+"</del>";
            //Increment solved words.
            this.solved++;
          }
          
      
        }
      }

      //Game over?
      if(this.solved == this.settings.words.length){
        this.gameOver();
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Game Over
   */
  WordSearch.prototype.gameOver = function() {
    //Create overlay.
    var overlay = document.createElement("div");
    overlay.setAttribute("id", "ws-game-over-outer");
    overlay.setAttribute("class", "ws-game-over-outer");
    this.wrapEl.parentNode.appendChild(overlay);

    //Create overlay content.
    var overlay = document.getElementById("ws-game-over-outer");
      overlay.innerHTML = "<div class='ws-game-over-inner' id='ws-game-over-inner'>"+
                            "<div class='ws-game-over' id='ws-game-over'>"+
                              "<h2>Congratulations!</h2>"+
                              "<p>You've found all of the words!</p>"+
                            "</div>"+
                          "</div>";
  }

  /**
   * MouseÂ event - Mouse down
   * @param {Object} item
   */
  WordSearch.prototype.onMousedown = function(item) {
    var _this = this;
    return function() {
      _this.selectFrom = item;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Mouse event - Mouse move
   * @param {Object}
   */
  WordSearch.prototype.onMouseover = function(item) {
    var _this = this;
    return function() {
      if (_this.selectFrom) {
        _this.selected = _this.getItems(_this.selectFrom.row, _this.selectFrom.col, item.row, item.col);

        _this.clearHighlight();

        for (var i = 0; i < _this.selected.length; i ++) {
          var current = _this.selected[i],
            row = current.row + 1,
            col = current.col + 1,
            el = document.querySelector('.ws-area .ws-row:nth-child(' + row + ') .ws-col:nth-child(' + col + ')');

          el.className += ' ws-selected';
        }
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Mouse event - Mouse up
   */
  WordSearch.prototype.onMouseup = function() {
    var _this = this;
    return function() {
      _this.selectFrom = null;
      _this.clearHighlight();
      _this.lookup(_this.selected);
      _this.selected = [];
    }
  }

})();
//-----------------------------Remove accent for latin/hebrew letters---------------------------------------------------//
var defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap = [{
    'base': "A",
        'letters': /(&#65;|&#9398;|&#65313;|&#192;|&#193;|&#194;|&#7846;|&#7844;|&#7850;|&#7848;|&#195;|&#256;|&#258;|&#7856;|&#7854;|&#7860;|&#7858;|&#550;|&#480;|&#196;|&#478;|&#7842;|&#197;|&#506;|&#461;|&#512;|&#514;|&#7840;|&#7852;|&#7862;|&#7680;|&#260;|&#570;|&#11375;|[\u0041\u24B6\uFF21\u00C0\u00C1\u00C2\u1EA6\u1EA4\u1EAA\u1EA8\u00C3\u0100\u0102\u1EB0\u1EAE\u1EB4\u1EB2\u0226\u01E0\u00C4\u01DE\u1EA2\u00C5\u01FA\u01CD\u0200\u0202\u1EA0\u1EAC\u1EB6\u1E00\u0104\u023A\u2C6F])/g
}, {
    'base': "AA",
        'letters': /(&#42802;|[\uA732])/g
}, {
    'base': "AE",
        'letters': /(&#198;|&#508;|&#482;|[\u00C6\u01FC\u01E2])/g
}, {
    'base': "AO",
        'letters': /(&#42804;|[\uA734])/g
}, {
    'base': "AU",
        'letters': /(&#42806;|[\uA736])/g
}, {
    'base': "AV",
        'letters': /(&#42808;|&#42810;|[\uA738\uA73A])/g
}, {
    'base': "AY",
        'letters': /(&#42812;|[\uA73C])/g
}, {
    'base': "B",
        'letters': /(&#66;|&#9399;|&#65314;|&#7682;|&#7684;|&#7686;|&#579;|&#386;|&#385;|[\u0042\u24B7\uFF22\u1E02\u1E04\u1E06\u0243\u0182\u0181])/g
}, {
    'base': "C",
        'letters': /(&#67;|&#9400;|&#65315;|&#262;|&#264;|&#266;|&#268;|&#199;|&#7688;|&#391;|&#571;|&#42814;|[\u0043\u24B8\uFF23\u0106\u0108\u010A\u010C\u00C7\u1E08\u0187\u023B\uA73E])/g
}, {
    'base': "D",
        'letters': /(&#68;|&#9401;|&#65316;|&#7690;|&#270;|&#7692;|&#7696;|&#7698;|&#7694;|&#272;|&#395;|&#394;|&#393;|&#42873;|&#208;|[\u0044\u24B9\uFF24\u1E0A\u010E\u1E0C\u1E10\u1E12\u1E0E\u0110\u018B\u018A\u0189\uA779\u00D0])/g
}, {
    'base': "DZ",
        'letters': /(&#497;|&#452;|[\u01F1\u01C4])/g
}, {
    'base': "Dz",
        'letters': /(&#498;|&#453;|[\u01F2\u01C5])/g
}, {
    'base': "E",
        'letters': /(&#69;|&#9402;|&#65317;|&#200;|&#201;|&#202;|&#7872;|&#7870;|&#7876;|&#7874;|&#7868;|&#274;|&#7700;|&#7702;|&#276;|&#278;|&#203;|&#7866;|&#282;|&#516;|&#518;|&#7864;|&#7878;|&#552;|&#7708;|&#280;|&#7704;|&#7706;|&#400;|&#398;|[\u0045\u24BA\uFF25\u00C8\u00C9\u00CA\u1EC0\u1EBE\u1EC4\u1EC2\u1EBC\u0112\u1E14\u1E16\u0114\u0116\u00CB\u1EBA\u011A\u0204\u0206\u1EB8\u1EC6\u0228\u1E1C\u0118\u1E18\u1E1A\u0190\u018E])/g
}, {
    'base': "F",
        'letters': /(&#70;|&#9403;|&#65318;|&#7710;|&#401;|&#42875;|[\u0046\u24BB\uFF26\u1E1E\u0191\uA77B])/g
}, {
    'base': "G",
        'letters': /(&#71;|&#9404;|&#65319;|&#500;|&#284;|&#7712;|&#286;|&#288;|&#486;|&#290;|&#484;|&#403;|&#42912;|&#42877;|&#42878;|[\u0047\u24BC\uFF27\u01F4\u011C\u1E20\u011E\u0120\u01E6\u0122\u01E4\u0193\uA7A0\uA77D\uA77E])/g
}, {
    'base': "H",
        'letters': /(&#72;|&#9405;|&#65320;|&#292;|&#7714;|&#7718;|&#542;|&#7716;|&#7720;|&#7722;|&#294;|&#11367;|&#11381;|&#42893;|[\u0048\u24BD\uFF28\u0124\u1E22\u1E26\u021E\u1E24\u1E28\u1E2A\u0126\u2C67\u2C75\uA78D])/g
}, {
    'base': "I",
        'letters': /(&#73;|&#9406;|&#65321;|&#204;|&#205;|&#206;|&#296;|&#298;|&#300;|&#304;|&#207;|&#7726;|&#7880;|&#463;|&#520;|&#522;|&#7882;|&#302;|&#7724;|&#407;|[\u0049\u24BE\uFF29\u00CC\u00CD\u00CE\u0128\u012A\u012C\u0130\u00CF\u1E2E\u1EC8\u01CF\u0208\u020A\u1ECA\u012E\u1E2C\u0197])/g
}, {
    'base': "J",
        'letters': /(&#74;|&#9407;|&#65322;|&#308;|&#584;|[\u004A\u24BF\uFF2A\u0134\u0248])/g
}, {
    'base': "K",
        'letters': /(&#75;|&#9408;|&#65323;|&#7728;|&#488;|&#7730;|&#310;|&#7732;|&#408;|&#11369;|&#42816;|&#42818;|&#42820;|&#42914;|[\u004B\u24C0\uFF2B\u1E30\u01E8\u1E32\u0136\u1E34\u0198\u2C69\uA740\uA742\uA744\uA7A2])/g
}, {
    'base': "L",
        'letters': /(&#76;|&#9409;|&#65324;|&#319;|&#313;|&#317;|&#7734;|&#7736;|&#315;|&#7740;|&#7738;|&#321;|&#573;|&#11362;|&#11360;|&#42824;|&#42822;|&#42880;|[\u004C\u24C1\uFF2C\u013F\u0139\u013D\u1E36\u1E38\u013B\u1E3C\u1E3A\u0141\u023D\u2C62\u2C60\uA748\uA746\uA780])/g
}, {
    'base': "LJ",
        'letters': /(&#455;|[\u01C7])/g
}, {
    'base': "Lj",
        'letters': /(&#456;|[\u01C8])/g
}, {
    'base': "M",
        'letters': /(&#77;|&#9410;|&#65325;|&#7742;|&#7744;|&#7746;|&#11374;|&#412;|[\u004D\u24C2\uFF2D\u1E3E\u1E40\u1E42\u2C6E\u019C])/g
}, {
    'base': "N",
        'letters': /(&#78;|&#9411;|&#65326;|&#504;|&#323;|&#209;|&#7748;|&#327;|&#7750;|&#325;|&#7754;|&#7752;|&#544;|&#413;|&#42896;|&#42916;|&#330;|[\u004E\u24C3\uFF2E\u01F8\u0143\u00D1\u1E44\u0147\u1E46\u0145\u1E4A\u1E48\u0220\u019D\uA790\uA7A4\u014A])/g
}, {
    'base': "NJ",
        'letters': /(&#458;|[\u01CA])/g
}, {
    'base': "Nj",
        'letters': /(&#459;|[\u01CB])/g
}, {
    'base': "O",
        'letters': /(&#79;|&#9412;|&#65327;|&#210;|&#211;|&#212;|&#7890;|&#7888;|&#7894;|&#7892;|&#213;|&#7756;|&#556;|&#7758;|&#332;|&#7760;|&#7762;|&#334;|&#558;|&#560;|&#214;|&#554;|&#7886;|&#336;|&#465;|&#524;|&#526;|&#416;|&#7900;|&#7898;|&#7904;|&#7902;|&#7906;|&#7884;|&#7896;|&#490;|&#492;|&#216;|&#510;|&#390;|&#415;|&#42826;|&#42828;|[\u004F\u24C4\uFF2F\u00D2\u00D3\u00D4\u1ED2\u1ED0\u1ED6\u1ED4\u00D5\u1E4C\u022C\u1E4E\u014C\u1E50\u1E52\u014E\u022E\u0230\u00D6\u022A\u1ECE\u0150\u01D1\u020C\u020E\u01A0\u1EDC\u1EDA\u1EE0\u1EDE\u1EE2\u1ECC\u1ED8\u01EA\u01EC\u00D8\u01FE\u0186\u019F\uA74A\uA74C])/g
}, {
    'base': "OE",
        'letters': /(&#338;|[\u0152])/g
}, {
    'base': "OI",
        'letters': /(&#418;|[\u01A2])/g
}, {
    'base': "OO",
        'letters': /(&#42830;|[\uA74E])/g
}, {
    'base': "OU",
        'letters': /(&#546;|[\u0222])/g
}, {
    'base': "P",
        'letters': /(&#80;|&#9413;|&#65328;|&#7764;|&#7766;|&#420;|&#11363;|&#42832;|&#42834;|&#42836;|[\u0050\u24C5\uFF30\u1E54\u1E56\u01A4\u2C63\uA750\uA752\uA754])/g
}, {
    'base': "Q",
        'letters': /(&#81;|&#9414;|&#65329;|&#42838;|&#42840;|&#586;|[\u0051\u24C6\uFF31\uA756\uA758\u024A])/g
}, {
    'base': "R",
        'letters': /(&#82;|&#9415;|&#65330;|&#340;|&#7768;|&#344;|&#528;|&#530;|&#7770;|&#7772;|&#342;|&#7774;|&#588;|&#11364;|&#42842;|&#42918;|&#42882;|[\u0052\u24C7\uFF32\u0154\u1E58\u0158\u0210\u0212\u1E5A\u1E5C\u0156\u1E5E\u024C\u2C64\uA75A\uA7A6\uA782])/g
}, {
    'base': "S",
        'letters': /(&#83;|&#9416;|&#65331;|&#7838;|&#346;|&#7780;|&#348;|&#7776;|&#352;|&#7782;|&#7778;|&#7784;|&#536;|&#350;|&#11390;|&#42920;|&#42884;|[\u0053\u24C8\uFF33\u1E9E\u015A\u1E64\u015C\u1E60\u0160\u1E66\u1E62\u1E68\u0218\u015E\u2C7E\uA7A8\uA784])/g
}, {
    'base': "T",
        'letters': /(&#84;|&#9417;|&#65332;|&#7786;|&#356;|&#7788;|&#538;|&#354;|&#7792;|&#7790;|&#358;|&#428;|&#430;|&#574;|&#42886;|[\u0054\u24C9\uFF34\u1E6A\u0164\u1E6C\u021A\u0162\u1E70\u1E6E\u0166\u01AC\u01AE\u023E\uA786])/g
}, {
    'base': "TH",
        'letters': /(&#222;|[\u00DE])/g
}, {
    'base': "TZ",
        'letters': /(&#42792;|[\uA728])/g
}, {
    'base': "U",
        'letters': /(&#85;|&#9418;|&#65333;|&#217;|&#218;|&#219;|&#360;|&#7800;|&#362;|&#7802;|&#364;|&#220;|&#475;|&#471;|&#469;|&#473;|&#7910;|&#366;|&#368;|&#467;|&#532;|&#534;|&#431;|&#7914;|&#7912;|&#7918;|&#7916;|&#7920;|&#7908;|&#7794;|&#370;|&#7798;|&#7796;|&#580;|[\u0055\u24CA\uFF35\u00D9\u00DA\u00DB\u0168\u1E78\u016A\u1E7A\u016C\u00DC\u01DB\u01D7\u01D5\u01D9\u1EE6\u016E\u0170\u01D3\u0214\u0216\u01AF\u1EEA\u1EE8\u1EEE\u1EEC\u1EF0\u1EE4\u1E72\u0172\u1E76\u1E74\u0244])/g
}, {
    'base': "V",
        'letters': /(&#86;|&#9419;|&#65334;|&#7804;|&#7806;|&#434;|&#42846;|&#581;|[\u0056\u24CB\uFF36\u1E7C\u1E7E\u01B2\uA75E\u0245])/g
}, {
    'base': "VY",
        'letters': /(&#42848;|[\uA760])/g
}, {
    'base': "W",
        'letters': /(&#87;|&#9420;|&#65335;|&#7808;|&#7810;|&#372;|&#7814;|&#7812;|&#7816;|&#11378;|[\u0057\u24CC\uFF37\u1E80\u1E82\u0174\u1E86\u1E84\u1E88\u2C72])/g
}, {
    'base': "X",
        'letters': /(&#88;|&#9421;|&#65336;|&#7818;|&#7820;|[\u0058\u24CD\uFF38\u1E8A\u1E8C])/g
}, {
    'base': "Y",
        'letters': /(&#89;|&#9422;|&#65337;|&#7922;|&#221;|&#374;|&#7928;|&#562;|&#7822;|&#376;|&#7926;|&#7924;|&#435;|&#590;|&#7934;|[\u0059\u24CE\uFF39\u1EF2\u00DD\u0176\u1EF8\u0232\u1E8E\u0178\u1EF6\u1EF4\u01B3\u024E\u1EFE])/g
}, {
    'base': "Z",
        'letters': /(&#90;|&#9423;|&#65338;|&#377;|&#7824;|&#379;|&#381;|&#7826;|&#7828;|&#437;|&#548;|&#11391;|&#11371;|&#42850;|[\u005A\u24CF\uFF3A\u0179\u1E90\u017B\u017D\u1E92\u1E94\u01B5\u0224\u2C7F\u2C6B\uA762])/g
},  {
    'base': "", //delete Niqqud in Hebrew
        'letters': /[\u0591-\u05C7]/g
}]

function removeDiacritics(str) {
    for (var i = 0; i < defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap.length; i++) {
        str = str.replace(defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap[i].letters, defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap[i].base);
    }
    return str;
}
//------------------------------Search language--------------------------------------------------//
// Determine what letters injected on grid
function searchLanguage(firstLetter)
{
    codefirstLetter = firstLetter.charCodeAt();
    var codeLetter = [65,90];
    if((codefirstLetter>=65) && (codefirstLetter<=90)) { // Latin
        return codeLetter = [65,90];
    }
    if((codefirstLetter>=1488) && (codefirstLetter<=1514)) { //Hebrew × -> ×ª
        return codeLetter = [1488,1514];
    }
    if((codefirstLetter>=913) && (codefirstLetter<=937))    { //Greek Î‘ -> Î©
        return codeLetter = [913,929]; //930 is blank
    }
    if((codefirstLetter>=1040) && (codefirstLetter<=1071))  { //Cyrillic Ð -> Ð¯
        return codeLetter = [1040,1071]; //930 is blank
    }
    if((codefirstLetter>=1569) && (codefirstLetter<=1610))  { //Arab
        return codeLetter = [1569,1594]; //Between 1595 and 1600, no letter
    }
    if((codefirstLetter>=19969) && (codefirstLetter<=40891))    { //Chinese
        return codeLetter = [19969,40891];
    }
    if((codefirstLetter>=12354) && (codefirstLetter<=12436))    { //Japan Hiragana
        return codeLetter = [12388,12418]; //Only no small letter
    }
    console.log("Letter not detected : "+firstLetter+":"+codefirstLetter);
    return codeLetter;
    
    
}
      var gameAreaEl = document.getElementById('ws-area');
      var gameobj = gameAreaEl.wordSearch();

      // Put words into `.ws-words`
      var words = gameobj.settings.wordsList,
        wordsWrap = document.querySelector('.ws-words');
      for (i in words) {
        var liEl = document.createElement('li');
        liEl.setAttribute('class', 'ws-word');
        liEl.innerText = words[i];
        wordsWrap.appendChild(liEl);
      }
```

```css
/* CSS reset */

body, h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

body {
  color: #333;
}

/* Common */

.fix {
  *zoom: 1;
}

.fix:after {
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  content: '';
}

/* Home */

.wrap {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 40px 0;
  text-align: center;
  position:relative;
}

.logo, #gameArea {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.ws-area, .ws-words {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.ws-words {
  margin-left: 20px;
  text-align: left;
}

.ws-word {
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.ws-words ::first-letter{
    text-transform : capitalize;
}
/* Wordsearch */

.ws-area {
  background: #fafafa;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}

.ws-row {
  line-height: 0;
}

.ws-col {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ws-col.ws-selected {
  background: #eee;
}

.ws-found {
  background: yellow;
}

.ws-game-over-outer {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.ws-game-over-inner {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  display:table;
}

.ws-game-over {
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.ws-game-over h2 {
  color:#FFFFFF;
  font-size:2em;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  padding:0;
  margin:0 0 9px 0;
}

.ws-game-over p {
  color:#FFFFFF;
  font-size:1em;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
      <h1 class="logo">Word search game</h1>
      <section id="ws-area"></section>
      <ul class="ws-words"></ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array = document.querySelector("#array");
const myWords = ["LOL", "HEY", "TOYS", "YES", "SIR", "JOY"]; 

let currentIndex = myWords.length;
while (currentIndex>0) {
  selectedWord = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
  currentIndex--;
    [myWords[currentIndex], myWords[selectedWord]] = [myWords[selectedWord], myWords[currentIndex]];
  var word = myWords[currentIndex];
  var length = word.length;

  var result = '';
  while(length > 0){
    var selectedLetter = Math.floor(Math.random() * length);
    result += word.charAt(selectedLetter);
    word = word.substring(0, selectedLetter) + word.substring(selectedLetter + 1, length);
    length--;
  }
  result += "<br>";
  array.innerHTML += result;
}
```

```html
<div id="array"></div>
```

Helpful?

Comment: this is not word search,its jumble word